# How to delete all Annotations on a MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, annotations, mkmapview

Is there a simple way to delete all the annotations on a map without iterating through all the displayed annotations in Objective-c?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Yes, here is how

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]
```

> However the previous line of code will remove all map annotations "PINS" from
>   the map, including the user location pin "Blue Pin". To remove all map
>   annotations and keep the user location pin on the map, there are two
>   possible ways to do that
>
> Example 1, retain the user location annotation, remove all pins, add
>   the user location pin back, but there is a flaw with this approach, it
>   will cause the user location pin to blink on the map, due to removing
>   the pin then adding it back

```
- (void)removeAllPinsButUserLocation1 
{
    id userLocation = [mapView userLocation];
    [mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];

    if ( userLocation != nil ) {
        [mapView addAnnotation:userLocation]; // will cause user location pin to blink
    }
}
```

> Example 2, I personally prefer to avoid removing the location user pin
>   in the first place,

```
- (void)removeAllPinsButUserLocation2
{
    id userLocation = [mapView userLocation];
    NSMutableArray *pins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[mapView annotations]];
    if ( userLocation != nil ) {
        [pins removeObject:userLocation]; // avoid removing user location off the map
    }

    [mapView removeAnnotations:pins];
    [pins release];
    pins = nil;
}
```

Comment: does this remove the user location too? what if I want to remove all the annotations besides the user location?

Comment: You do not need to save any reference to user location. Read my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 35):

Here is the simplest way to do that:

```
-(void)removeAllAnnotations
{
  //Get the current user location annotation.
  id userAnnotation=mapView.userLocation;

  //Remove all added annotations
  [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]; 

  // Add the current user location annotation again.
  if(userAnnotation!=nil)
  [mapView addAnnotation:userAnnotation];
}
```

Comment: Good answer, much faster than iterating through all of them, especially if you have more than a handful of annotations.

Comment: Removing an annotation then adding it back, causes the pin to blink on the map. Might not a be a big deal for some apps, but it can be annoying for the user if you consistently updating the map with new annotations.

Comment: For some reason, my userLocation annotation always disappears using this method.  Victor Van Hee's solution works for me.

Comment: horrible solution, it blinks

Answer (score 18):

Here's how to remove all annotations except the user location, written out explicitly because I imagine I will come looking for this answer again:

```
NSMutableArray *locs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id <MKAnnotation> annot in [mapView annotations])
{
    if ( [annot isKindOfClass:[ MKUserLocation class]] ) {
    }
    else {
        [locs addObject:annot];
    }
}
[mapView removeAnnotations:locs];
[locs release];
locs = nil;
```

Comment: Thank you,This worked for me with copy and paste and removing [locs release] and changing mapView to _mapView. I was following a great tutorial for MKDirections here http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial and wanted to remove the pin after getting directions. I added the code below the last line of that method to the 'clear route'method

Comment: update remove multiple   - (IBAction)clearRoute:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    self.destinationLabel.text = nil;
    self.distanceLabel.text = nil;
   
    self.steps.text = nil;
    [self.mapView removeOverlay:routeDetails.polyline];
    NSMutableArray *locs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annot in [_mapView annotations])
    {
        if ( [annot isKindOfClass:[ MKUserLocation class]] ) {
        }
        else {
            [locs addObject:annot];
        }
    }
    [_mapView removeAnnotations:locs];
    [_mapView removeOverlays:_mapView.overlays];
    
    
}

Answer (score 13):

This is very similar to Sandip's answer, except that it doesn't re-add the user location so the blue dot doesn't blink on and off again.

```
-(void)removeAllAnnotations
{
    id userAnnotation = self.mapView.userLocation;

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.mapView.annotations];
    [annotations removeObject:userAnnotation];

    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:annotations];
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You do not need to save any reference to user location. All that is needed is:

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

And as long as you have `mapView.showsUserLocation` set to `YES`, you will still have user location on the map. Settings this property to `YES` basically asks the map view to start updating and fetching user location, to to show it on the map. From the `MKMapView.h` comments:

```
// Set to YES to add the user location annotation to the map and start updating its location
```

Comment: I ended up using this format: [self.mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)]

Answer (score 8):

Swift 2.0
Simple and the best:

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift version:

```
func removeAllAnnotations() {
    let annotations = mapView.annotations.filter {
        $0 !== self.mapView.userLocation
    }
    mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3

```
if let annotations = self.mapView.annotations {
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove one type of subclass you can do

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations.filter({$0 is PlacesAnnotation}))
```

where `PlacesAnnotation` is a subclass of `MKAnnotation`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to remove all **markers** as well as all **routes (if any)** from MKMapView:

```
 func removeAppleMapOverlays() {
    let overlays = self.appleMapView.overlays
    self.appleMapView.removeOverlays(overlays)
    let annotations = self.appleMapView.annotations.filter {
            $0 !== self.appleMapView.userLocation
        }
    self.appleMapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

**Cheers**