# The removeAnnotations for MKMapView

Tags: objective-c

Why is it so useful to delete annotations?

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
```

It doesn't work.do this:

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
```

The system definition：

```
- (void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray<id<MKAnnotation>> *)annotations;
```

Comment: Please confirm if your question is about the syntax of the mentioned function? Have you checked this answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027392

Answer (score 0):

If the question is really WHY, this is what you can find reading the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452409-removeannotation?language=objc) :

> If the annotation is currently associated with an annotation view, and
> that view has a reuse identifier, this method **removes the annotation
> view and queues it internally for later reuse.** You can retrieve queued
> annotation views (and associate them with new annotations) using the
> dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: method.
>
> Removing an
> annotation object **disassociates it from the map view entirely,
> preventing it from being displayed on the map.** Thus, you would
> typically call this method only when you want to hide or delete a
> given annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but，It doesn't work.do this: ```self.mapView.annotations```
why???