# How to remove any MKPointAnnotation on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I have a search bar with allows me to fetch Location, Latitude and Longitude. When i get the values, the map shows the annotation perfectly.

Problem : When i select another location, lat, long previous data remains there.

What i need : I want to remove that previous particular location when ever i click the search button.

Code :

```
double searchLAT = [_searchedLat doubleValue];
double searchLONG = [_searchedLong doubleValue];

MKUserLocation *userlocation = [[MKUserLocation alloc] init];
userlocation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(searchLAT, searchLONG);

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userlocation.coordinate, 700000, 700000);
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(searchLAT,searchLONG);
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

Comment: Did you try to call `removeAnnotation:` on the map view?

Comment: is not clear `I want to remove that previous location` -- you want to clear previous all markers or particular location markers

Comment: No. Can you get me the right line of code @AndreasOetjen

Comment: Particular one @Anbu.karthik

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027392/how-to-delete-all-annotations-on-a-mkmapview

Comment: @HappilyHemu `[mapView removeAnnotation:YOUR_ANNOTATION_TO_REMOVE];`

Comment: @HappilyHemu if you want to remove all then --> `[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];`

Comment: Thanks. The solution works @AndreasOetjen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all Annotations on a MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027392/how-to-delete-all-annotations-on-a-mkmapview)

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize userlocation in the function. Make it global for your controller so only lat-long change but for MKUserLocation not allocate memory every time.